# NPP_GetValue() and invoke() method of plugin not getting called in safari 5.1

Tags: macos, plugins, safari

I have developed a 32 bit NPAPI plugin . This plugin has a native function which returns the plugin version. I have installed this bundle file under Library/Internet Plugin folder . I have a test html page with a button . On click of this button the version of the plugin will be displayed in alert box. In safari 5 in 32 bit mode this plugin works fine and it gives me the version.

BUt in safari 5.1 in 32 bit mode on click of the button i am unable to get the version .

call flow in safari 5 : 
NP_Initialize()->NP_GetEntryPoints()->NPP_New()->NPP_GetValue(). 
On click of button NPP_GetValue()->invoke()->plugin  method.

call flow in safari 5.1 :
NP_Initialize()->NP_GetEntryPoints()->NPP_New()
on click of button nothing happens.

here is an extract of my HTML file:

```
    <HTML>
<HEAD>

</HEAD>

<BODY>
<td><input type='button' name=version id='version' value='version' 
    onclick="javascript:version()"/>
</td>
<object id="pluginobj" type="application/my-p"></object>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript1.3">
function version()
{
        window.alert(document.getElementById("pluginobj").version());

}
</SCRIPT>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem with my plugin now in Safari 5.1. Did you manage to solve it somehow?

Comment: no not yet. did u get any pointers?